# Can a C# class inherit from a C++/cx class

Tags: c#, inheritance, c++-cx

I have defined a class in a "windows runtime component" project in c++/cx (UWP project). And I want to inherit that class in a c# UWP project

```
namespace WindowsRuntimeComponent1
{
    public ref class NetCapability
    {
    protected:
        virtual Platform::String^ GetName() { return L"NetCapability"; }

        virtual void OnConnected() {};
        virtual void OnDisconnected() {};
    };
}
```

when a C# class inherits from `NetCapability`, compiles it and errors occured

> WindowsRuntimeComponent1::NetCapability': A WinRT 'public ref class' must either be sealed or derive from an existing unsealed class

and the virtual function cannot be public.

So a c# class cannot inherit from a c++/cx public class ??